# Streaming music paid app

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, applications, music, streaming

I am getting really annoyed by the number of ads that I get in Pandora and am considering shelling out $36 for the paid version.

Are there other streaming music iPhone apps that I can review before I make a purchase?

This will be used in USA.

Comment: Not an answer (so not posted as an answer), but I'm very happy with the paid version of Pandora - I just re-upped for my second year. Not sure if the endorsement is helpful or not.

Comment: Ditto on the paid Pandora endorsement. I've subscribed to it (and also Rhapsody) for years, and consider them to be excellent investments.

Comment: [Spotify](http://www.spotify.com/) of course! But you'll need a lot of trickery to get it if you're not in a supporting country (and that's why I'm not adding it as an answer).

Comment: I'm an Rdio subscriber. Luke warm on it. The selection is pretty good (even with me being in Canada) but the iPhone app is sort of meh. The desktop app and web UI are very good though.

Answer (score 2):

You can download and try [Mog](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mog/id372093286?mt=8) and [Rdio](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rdio/id335060889?mt=8) for two weeks a piece.  They both also provide Desktop streaming as well.  I've tried both and prefer Mog.

Answer (score 2):

Hands down, I would go with [MOG](http://mog.com). It's cheap, fast, and compatible on most devices (iOS, Android, web, Roku, Mac, Windows). Option to stream songs for quick listening or download individual songs (64 kbps AAC+ normal or 320 kbps MP3s HQ).

Searchable by track, artist, album with the addition of streaming radio stations similar to what Pandora offers.

I've tried several services over the years, but MOG stands out with their [higher accessibility and listening options](http://mog.com/promos/overview).

Answer (score 2):

I *highly* recommend [Spotify](http://www.spotify.com/). The Mac version is free and ad-supported, or you can pay $10/month for ad-free listening, offline mode, iPhone (etc.) support, and a host of other features. There's also Unlimited for a few dollars less, but it does practically nothing but get rid of ads.

Another major bonus over Pandora, MOG, last.fm, etc. is that you can specify what tracks, albums, and artists are played. You can make playlists, share music with friends, or even listen to Pandora-style "similar artists" playlists.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you've got a large library at home and would like to stream your library to your iOS device, [Audiogalaxy](http://audiogalaxy.com/) is a great **free** option. It works like a charm and is ad free.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You  could go spotify or soundcloud i dont know but soundcloud have a deal on there where if you pay 5.99 i dont know how much they change it in the us but

Comment: Spotify is already a suggestion and deals are timely. Is SoundCloud usually the cheapest such that that's a reason to go with them?